# Getting a Value Error when fitting my tensorflow model

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

import numpy
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import random
import json

with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)


words = []
labels = []
docs_x = []
docs_y = []


for intent in data["intents"]:
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
        wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(wrds)
        docs_x.append(wrds)
        docs_y.append(intent["tag"])
        
    if intent["tag"] not in labels:
        labels.append(intent["tag"])
        
words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]
words = sorted(list(set(words)))

labels = sorted(labels) 

training = []
output = []

out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

for x,doc in enumerate (docs_x):
    bag = []
    
    wrds = [stemmer.stem(w) for w in doc]
    
    for w in words:
        if w in wrds:
            bag.append(1)
        else:
            bag.append(0)
            
    output_row = out_empty[:]
    output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1
    
    training.append(bag)
    output.append(output_row)
    
training = numpy.array(training)
output = numpy.array(output)

tensorflow.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training)])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net,8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net,8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net,len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)
model.fit(training,output, n_epoch=1000,batch_size=8, show_metric=True )
model.save("model.tflearn")
```

I'm trying to build a tensorflow model. So I'm getting a value error when I fit my tensorflow model. I believe my training and output numpy array might be causing the problem. But I'm not exactly sure how to fix it. Or am I fitting the model incorrectly? I'm also adding into the fitting various performance metrics which should display. Only outputs this and then throws an error.

```
Training samples: 26
Validation samples: 0
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error message so we can help better? Also, it'd be great if you can post a few examples in code of the contents of `intents.json` so we can reproduce this example.

Comment: Provide complete error log to investigate the root cause of this issue. Thanks!